# R710 & MD1220 PERC questions

Tags: raid, dell-poweredge, dell-perc

I'm purchasing a new database server (R710) with a direct attached storage (MD1220) device behind it.  I'm not up to date on the latest RAID technologies and needed some advice.  The MD1220 I've configured comes with the PERC H800 controller.

Do I need a PERC adapter on the database server (R710) as well?  I see there are several options, such as: PERC 6/E SAS External RAID Adapter, 512MB.  I just want to make sure we're ordering the correct items we need.

The server I'm replacing is fairly old and just used internal storage.  Any advice on what I need on each machine would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can remember when I set up something similar (It's been a couple years), the PERC H800 will be installed on the host server (in this case, your database server).  From there you connect to the DAS via a mini-SAS cable.  You can look at [this pdf](http://i.dell.com/sites/content/business/solutions/engineering-docs/en/Documents/storage-powervault-md12x0-technical-guidebook.pdf) under sections 5.7 and 5.8 for more info.

Comment: So when I order the MD1220, the H800 card is actually meant to be installed in my R710?

Comment: Yep, I'm pretty sure that's how it works.  Then you run the mini-SAS over to the DAS box and connect it.  Easy, peasy.

Comment: We installed a PERC H800 in an R610 to hook up an MD1220, so I imagine the R710 is the same.